# django filter for template

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I try to filter data in tepmplate this way:

```
{% if devtypes %}
<ul>
  {% for devtype in devtypes %}
    <li> <h3> {{devtype.name}} </h3> ( {{devtype.desc}} )
      <ul>
      {% for device in devices %}
        {% if device.devtype == devtype %}
        <li><h4>{{device}}</h4></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

And here are my models:

```
class Devtype(models.Model):
    pk_devtype=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Device(models.Model):
   pk_device=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   devtype=models.ForeignKey('Devtype', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
   login=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
   password=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
   ip=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
   desc=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

I think that my way is wrong and I should replace this part

```
{% if device.devtype == devtype %}
```

with something like a filter. Please help.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, what is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to get records many to one in template (device to devtype). I need a list of devtypes and a list of devices of each devtype after every devtype. `code`
CISCO
  switch 1
  router 2
HUAWEI
  switch 3
  router 4 `code`

Comment: `def index(request):`
`        devtypes=Devtype.objects.order_by('name')`
`   devices=Device.objects.all()`
` template=loader.get_template('b1/index.html')`
` context=RequestContext(request, {`
`  'devtypes':devtypes, 'devices':devices`
` })`
 
` return HttpResponse(template.render(context))`

Answer (score 4):

When you create a foreign key, django automatically creates a reverse relation; described in the documentation under [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

You need to utilize it in your template, like this:

```
{% if devtypes %}
<ul>
  {% for devtype in devtypes %}
    <li> <h3> {{devtype.name}} </h3> ( {{devtype.desc}} )
      <ul>
      {% for device in devtype.device_set.all %}
        <li><h4>{{device}}</h4></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```